# Qt Virtual Keyboard Bug in Lubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5, pyside2, qtvirtualkeyboard

I'm trying to active a Qt Virtual Keyboard whenever user touch a any textinput.

I Can call Qt Virtual Keyboard like this command :

```
os.environ["QT_IM_MODULE"] = "qtvirtualkeyboard"
```

In Ubuntu and Xubuntu Virtual Keyboard works fine.Here is the result :

[image: Xubuntu Virtual Keyboard]

But in Lubuntu virtual keyboard looks like this :

[image: Lubuntu Virtual Keyboard]

I can see the output of virtual keyboard in Xubuntu and Ubuntu but i cannot see in Lubuntu.

What could be reason for this bug and how can i fix it ?